# cloudant full text search among a sub-groups of documents

Tags: cloudant

I am building a messaging system with Cloudant, comprised of 'message' and 'membership' documents:

message documents:

```
{"_id":"1","type"="message","group":"a","text":"this is message 1"},
{"_id":"2","type"="message","group":"a","text":"this is message 2"},
{"_id":"3","type"="message","group":"b","text":"this is message 3"},
...
```

membership documents:

```
{"_id":"a","type"="membership","user":"joe","group":"a"},
{"_id":"b","type"="membership","user":"bob","group":"a"},
{"_id":"c","type"="membership","user":"bob","group":"b"},
...
```

Each message is associated with one group.  A user may have a membership in hundreds of different groups.

I would like to perform full text searches on the message text, on behalf of a particular user.  The application requires that users must not see messages from groups that they are not members of.

how can I do a full text search that returns only messages from groups that a particular user belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do this by making a smart search string.  To set this up, when you write your search index function, index the message's group as well as the message text.  For instance:

```
function(doc){
  index("group", doc.group);
  index("text", doc.text);
}
```

Then, when querying this index, use the [lucene syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description) to build a search string containing all of the user's membership.

```
(group:a or group:b or group:c or ...) and text:"search string goes here"
```

Comment: I wonder if this solution would still be practical if a user belonged to hundreds of groups. Are there size limitations on the lucene query string?