# Maximum lucene query string length in cloudant?

Tags: cloudant

Is there a maximum length to a lucene query string in cloudant?

I would like to do a query that looks something like this:

```
(group:1 OR group:2 OR ... OR group:N ) and text:"search string goes here"
```

The "..." in the above string represents up to N repetitions of "OR"s.

Is there a limit to how big N can be? would 100 be ok? how about 1000?

If you are wondering why I want to do a query like this in the first place, please see my related question: [cloudant full text search among a sub-groups of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585689/cloudant-full-text-search-among-a-sub-groups-of-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudant doesn't impose any limits on querystring length, but your browser might. [As this thread discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), play it safe and keep queries to under 2000 characters.

Comment: Contextualizing this for your linked question, you could always do multiple queries, since it's an OR clause. Especially if done in parallel, that might be faster than a single tremendous query.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be the case, I get a 400 “too many Boolean requests”